# List of all commands that cause git gc --auto

Tags: git, msysgit, git-gc

Is there a definitive list of commands anywhere that cause `git gc --auto` to run? The [git-gc(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-gc) simply states:

> --auto
>
> With this option, git gc checks whether any housekeeping is required; if not, it exits without performing any work. **Some git commands** run `git gc --auto` after performing operations that could create many loose objects.

(emphasis added)

I'm in the process of organising a large migration from SVN to Git. The overwhelming majority of users will be on Windows PCs, and a not-insignificant portion of them are non-technical. They will be using TortoiseGit (as it closely matches TortoiseSVN, which they are already familiar with) - I've noticed that TortoiseGit does not include any functionality to run `git gc` manually at all.

The non-technical staff cannot be expected to have to launch a "git bash" command line to run `git gc --auto` from the appropriate working dir; and as we are using the "portable" distribution of MsysGit they will not have the "Git GUI Here.."  windows shell context menu shortcut.

Is it reasonable to expect that over time Git will mostly self-maintain, or do I need to try and work out a non-technical user friendly method of invoking `git gc --auto`?

Comment: Note: `git rebase` will soon handle `git gc --auto` in a more sensible way: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35033755/6309

Comment: Don't forget `git commit`, starting with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49216495/6309)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
builtin/merge.c:            const char *argv_gc_auto[] = { "gc", "--auto", NULL };
builtin/receive-pack.c:     "gc", "--auto", "--quiet", NULL,
git-am.sh:                  git gc --auto
git-rebase--interactive.sh: git gc --auto &&
git-svn.perl:               command_noisy('gc', '--auto');
```

From `git grep -- --auto` on git.git, those results looked interesting. The notable one is `builtin/merge.c` meaning that the ever so common `git pull` should trigger a `git gc --auto`.

Additionally, unless your 'non-technical' staff is doing rather 'advanced' stuff (at which point they wouldn't be 'non-technical' anymore), I don't see why they would ever need to run `git gc` manually instead of just letting `git gc --auto` handle everything.

Comment: Agreed: `auto` is for "automatic", i.e. the average user doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: I understand that `--auto` is supposed to be behind-the-scenes stuff, but was also curious if it gets invoked often enough that one can _rely_ on `--auto` to perform `gc`. I've seen other questions asking things like "how often should I run `git gc`?", but couldn't work out if `--auto` got called often enough that users could essentially never need to think about manually running `git gc`. I'll mark this as accepted since it has the list of commands, thanks Arrowmaster.  I'm still curious if people think `--auto` is good enough, or if users should still do manual `git gc` on occasion.

Comment: I sometimes use git to backup my files. In those repos a cronjob only performs `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` commands. None of those will trigger a `git gc --auto`. In that situation therefore I cannot rely upon the automatic cleaning and should do a `git gc` or `git repack` manually.

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), you will have to add `git commit` to the list of commands triggering a `git gc --auto`.
Actually, that should have been the case since the beginning of Git.

See [commit 095c741](https://github.com/git/git/commit/095c741edd1d9604b6c285000a836721fd69f051) (28 Feb 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9bb8eb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bb8eb0c88d210d3575bd484320f9abfef551ed1), 08 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `commit`: run `git gc --auto` just before the `post-commit` hook
>
> Change the behavior of `git-commit` back to what it was back in
>   [d4bb43e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4bb43ee273528064192848165f93f8fc3512be1) ("Invoke "`git gc --auto`" from `commit`, `merge`, `am` and
>   `rebase`.", 2007-09-05, Git v1.5.4-rc0) when it was `git-commit.sh`.
>
> Shortly afterwards in [f5bbc32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5bbc3225c4b073a7ff3218164a0c820299bc9c6) ("Port `git commit` to C.", 2007-11-08, Git v1.5.4-rc0) when it was ported to C, the "`git gc --auto`" invocation went away.
>
> Since that unintended regression, `git gc --auto` only ran for `git-am`,
>   `git-merge`, `git-fetch`, and `git-receive-pack`.
>   It was possible to write a script that would "`git commit`" a lot of data locally, and `gc` would never run.
>
> One such repository that was locally committing generated zone file
>   changes had grown to a size of ~60GB before a daily cronjob was added
>   to "`git gc`", bringing it down to less than 1GB. This will make such
>   cases work without intervention.
>
> I think fixing such pathological cases where the repository will grow
>   forever is a worthwhile trade-off for spending a couple of
>   milliseconds calling "`git gc --auto`" (in the common cases where it
>   doesn't do anything).

---

You can find another illustration of this list with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), which teach "`am`", "`commit`", "`merge`" and "`rebase`", when they are run with the "`--quiet`" option, to pass "`--quiet`" down to "`gc --auto`".

See [commit 7c3e9e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c3e9e8cfbf6a8e45f4745049dc58f5c9e9d1eb9), [commit 850b6ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/850b6edefa7a4fcc75149447cb8a984f804dd080) (06 May 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3af459e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3af459e48dd275665568f3a7a6d76d90c1843e6a), 13 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`auto-gc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/850b6edefa7a4fcc75149447cb8a984f804dd080): extract a reusable helper from "`git fetch`"
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
>
> Back in [1991006c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1991006cb9c84ec11de8a5ebf9e419f0ac1f00d0) (`fetch`: convert `argv_gc_auto` to struct `argv_array`, 2014-08-16, Git v2.1.1), we taught "`git fetch --quiet`" to pass the "`--quiet`" option down to "`gc --auto`".
>
> This issue, however, is not limited to "fetch":
>
> ```
> $ git grep -e 'gc.*--auto' \*.c
> ```
>
> finds hits in "`am`", "`commit`", "`merge`", and "`rebase`" and these commands do not pass "`--quiet`" down to "`gc --auto`" when they themselves are told to be quiet.
>
> As a preparatory step, let's introduce a helper function `run_auto_gc()`, that the caller can pass a boolean "`quiet`", and redo the fix to "`git fetch`" using the helper.