# Git - merge current version to next version removes code from next version

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm facing a strange issue that never happened before and I'm not sure what is the cause.

At the moment we have two *develop* branches. Let's call them `foo` (v 3.x) and `bar` (v 4.x).
The logic behind is that in the `bar` branch we develop new functionality that is not deserved in `foo`. But at the same time we want to have all the changes done in `foo` merged to `bar` after some time.

Our usual way of doing that was by creating new branch: `foo-to-bar` which branches from `foo` has all changes pulled to it from `bar` and when the possible conflicts are resolved we open a PR to `bar`.

It doesn't work at the moment, this is what happening:

```
// `bar` contains following changes
   - A
   - B
   - C
   - D

// I create new branch from `foo` and checkout
   - foo-to-bar

// I pull the changes from `bar` to this new branch
   - git pull origin bar

// I get the some conflicts and this is how it looks
   - A > deleted by us [`foo`] and modified by them [`bar`], can be solved
   - B > deleted by us [`foo`] and modified by them [`bar`], can be solved
   - C > deleted/not pulled? without notifying
   - D > deleted/not pulled? without notifying
   - and multiple deletions of `bar` changes within non conflicted files
```

If I branch `foo-to-bar` from `bar` and pull changes to it from `foo` I'll get the same result but have more staged changes visible.

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it? Would `rebase` help in this case?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the tip from @**j6t** we were able to locate cause of the issue.
So what happened is that at some point `bar` was merged to **feature branch** of `foo` but since that's not correct this merge was reverted.AN this revert contains deletions of multiple files (A,B,C,D etc.).

Any idea how to deal with this? How to presuade `foo` that those changes should not be deleted?

Comment: You should make an ASCII drawing of the history starting at the last common commit of `foo` and `bar`. Mark the commits where changes to A, B, C, D happen, and also where some of them were deleted. If you want to make the histories visible in a UI, use `gitk foo-to-bar...origin/bar` (not the three dots).

Comment: thanks for a tip, I'll give it a try

Comment: I'm not quite willing to close-as-duplicate immediately, but see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143660/1256452).

Comment: I was thinking of asking to close it anyway as I have found the cause of issue and the solution kind of requires another question. Thanks for the link