# Git rebase gets stuck after resolving merge conflict

Tags: git

I'm running a rebase that hits a conflict:

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Better `SelectMotifsView.js`
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       browser/AddLinkView.js
M       browser/SelectMotifsView.js
M       browser/index.html
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging browser/index.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in browser/index.html
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Better `SelectMotifsView.js`
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /Users/dmitry/dev/links/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

No biggie—I had made a small change that I knew would cause a conflict:

```
diff --cc browser/index.html
index ba9c4f3,4c2a1c2..0000000
--- a/browser/index.html
+++ b/browser/index.html
@@@ -40,6 -40,7 +40,10 @@@
              <label>
                  <%= label %>
                  <select class="form-control" name="motif">
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++=======
+                     <% console.log(exclude); %>
++>>>>>>> Better `SelectMotifsView.js`
                      <% motifs.each(function(motif) { if (!exclude || exclude.indexOf(motif) < 0) { %>
                          <option value="<%= motif.get('id') %>"><%= motif.get('name') %></option>
                      <% } }); %>
```

I want to keep the version from `HEAD`, which is empty, so I go in and just remove the whole:

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++=======
+                     <% console.log(exclude); %>
++>>>>>>> Better `SelectMotifsView.js`
```

I save the file, `browser/index.html`, then `git add browser/index.html`:

```
$ git add browser/index.html
$ git rebase --continue
```

But then:

```
Applying: Better `SelectMotifsView.js`
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Never seen this before... `git status` shows no remaining unresolved paths. What to do? I read on other related questions that this may be a good use of `--skip`, but this doesn't seem to be a null commit. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The slightly puzzling part is the three `M`-status files.  With just one conflict that's resolved by choosing to leave the file unchanged, there should be two other changed files.  But perhaps those were auto-resolved to "no change" after all?  (I can't tell for sure, from the above.)

Comment: it asks you `No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?`. what is that answer?

Comment: @jessh: Yes, you can see in my question: I use `git add` on the file that was in conflict. There was no other unresolved paths.

Comment: @torek: Yeah, those were modified along the rebase path, but they didn't experience conflict so they were auto-merged. I pasted all the output... so you know all that I know.

Comment: I've never seen `git rebase` report this for commits that actually did modify something, so I'd try the `--skip`.

Comment: It looks like the auto-merge result was "same as without this patch".  Which means that since the manual merge result was *also* "same as without this patch", the patch winds up empty, and can be omitted.  (If you want to keep it anyway, you can manually commit with `--allow-empty`, or try `--keep-empty` although the source suggests the latter won't work at this point.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like the patch is empty, so you can safely skip it as git suggests:

```
$ git rebase --skip
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible cause of a `git rebase` being stuck in a "rebase loop" is `git gc`.
This is fixed in [git 2.7.1 (February 6th, 2016)](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.7.1)

See [commit 8c24f5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c24f5b022095f4735fcb73364ccae7d97576636) (13 Jan 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit eefc461](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eefc461ce3f2f0405639ff0919b844a894d6a02c), 26 Jan 2016)</sup>

> ### `rebase`: ignore failures from "`gc --auto`"
>
> After rebasing, we call "`gc --auto`" to clean up if we created a lot of loose objects. However, we do so inside an `&&`-chain. If "`gc --auto`" fails (e.g., because a previous background gc blocked us by leaving "`gc.log`" in place), then:
>
> 1. We will fail to clean up the state directory, leaving the user stuck in the rebase forever (even "`git am --abort`" doesn't work, because it calls "`gc --auto`"!).
> 2. In some cases, we may return a bogus exit code from rebase, indicating failure when everything except the auto-gc succeeded.
>
> We can fix this by ignoring the exit code of "`gc --auto`".

So to fix you just need to remove `gc.log`:

```
rm .git/gc.log
```