# Git: When does Git perform garbage collection?

Tags: git, version-control, garbage-collection, git-gc

I was wondering: when does Git perform its garbage collection? I know that in the past one had to invoke `git gc` to manually start the garbage collection, but now it is done automatically, when?

Also, is there a need to invoke it manually in the latest Git versions?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137447

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Much of the answer is in the [`git gc` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html):

> `--auto`
>
> With this option, *git gc* checks whether any housekeeping is required; if not, it exits without performing any work. Some git commands run `git gc --auto` after performing operations that could create many loose objects.
>
> Housekeeping is required if there are too many loose objects or too many packs in the repository. If the number of loose objects exceeds the value of the `gc.auto` configuration variable, then all loose objects are combined into a single pack using `git repack -d -l`. Setting the value of `gc.auto` to 0 disables automatic packing of loose objects.
>
> If the number of packs exceeds the value of `gc.autopacklimit`, then existing packs (except those marked with a `.keep` file) are consolidated into a single pack by using the `-A` option of `git repack`. Setting `gc.autopacklimit` to 0 disables automatic consolidation of packs.

The only thing missing here is an explanation of which "some" commands might run `git gc --auto`, and when.  This list is subject to change, but looking at current git source, these stand out:

```
git fetch
git merge
git receive-pack
git am
git rebase
```

(this is from `git grep -e --auto -- '*.c' '*.sh'` and eyeball-excluding all the `t/` tests scripts and other obvious false hits).  If you want something more in depth, the source to git is on `github.com`...

Note: [with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49216495/6309), you need to consider also:

```
git commit
```