# Does git gc execute at deterministic intervals?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I've been reading up on git, and I have a very particular question I am struggling to answer.

**When** does `git gc` execute autonomously?

I've been hearing through the grape-vine of various forums that it occurs by default on a push or a fetch/pull - but I cannot find any source that verifies this. Even [the documentation itself](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) only gets this specific (emphasis mine):

> **Some** git commands **may** automatically run git gc; see the --auto flag below for details

and the `--auto` flag specifies

> **Some** git commands run git gc --auto after performing operations that could create many loose objects.

I want to be able to deterministically say:

"Loose tree and blob files will not have been cleaned up by git until one of the following commands is run: **{mystery list here}**. When running one of these commands, if the number of loose objects exceeds the value of `gc.auto`, git will automatically compress the objects into a packfile".

Comment: maybe it's intentionally vague to not constrain future versions?

Comment: maybe, but I'd like some kind of official verification - one way or another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently those are:

- fetch
- merge
- am
- receive-pack
- commit ([starting with Git 2.17, Q2 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49216495/6309))

Actual list can be verified by doing a [code search](https://github.com/git/git/search?l=C&q=gc+auto&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Also from that you can see that gc on receive can be disabled with `receive.autogc`, others just run the gc in the end.